# Some questions about web server permissions

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I have made a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 and later installed Apache2, PHP, and MySQL. I started to read about file permissions for web servers. I am confused to what happened to the www-data group. Is this group no longer necessary? Finally, what are the recommended permissions for webserver?

I did the following command:
`sudo ls -l /var/www/html`

which output:

````
total 56
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  6840 May  6 19:48 apple-touch-icon2.png
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12482 May  6 19:48 apple-touch-icon.png
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 11321 May  6 19:48 index2.html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   233 May  6 19:48 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 May  6 19:48 pdf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    20 May  6 19:49 phpinfo.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 May  6 19:58 TVP
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 May  6 20:19 wiki```
````

Comment: Let's start with `cat /etc/group | grep www-data` and see if that group exists!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yes, it looks like it does exist. I get the output: `www-data:x:33:`.

Comment: So it's up to you to change ownership of that dir and files to 'www-data'

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I see. So I need to change the ownership from root to 'www-data' both user and group?

Comment: Add yourself to the www-data then change group ownership to www-data and user ownership to your user... but note any new operations there will still make ownership of `root:root` so make it permanent using setfacl so any new operations will always set it to `$USER:www-data` See: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/setfacl.1.html

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Thanks for the help!

Comment: Remember to make the permissions therein `775`!